# What is the best way to make a doorway that suits a curved object like that?

Tags: geometry, topology

I made this weirdly shaped wall and wanted to create a doorway to the next room that wouldn't have a gap in between. I've tried a lot of things, but my lack of experience doesn't allow me to solve the problem. What would be the best solution? I'll include the blend file. Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just rebuilt the whole thing, like you suggested, but I'll keep looking for answer. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: hey, glad something worked for you!   If it worked for you, can you click the check icon below the up/downvote markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote?   Rebuild the wavy wall: Start with a wall that already has the doorway cut out of it and re-do the deformations, maybe even just shrink-wrap the new wall against the existing wavy wall.

---

[image: Duplicated wall geometry, being separated from the source object..]
First, I separated three faces from the existing wall into it's own object.

---

[image]
Next, I subdivided the wall manually so it had even topology. It also needed some cleanup from having a co-incident edge in there.)

---

[image]
I then gave it another sub-d modifier and applied the shrink-wrap modifier to project this mesh against the existing wavy wall.

---

[image]
I then grabbed an edge loop of the doorway and extruded inward.

---

[image]
The advantage now is that you can adjust the subdivision and shrink-wrap parameters.
Try this technique out and let us know if it works for you.